# HttpResponseMessage Send & Receive List or Array of <T>

Tags: .net-core, blazor

With the latest System.Net.Http.Json there are some methods that help with serializing / deserializing. I want to use the HttpResponseMessage Content hold my response Objects. They seem to store fine on the server but when I get them on the client side the Content is not what I was expecting. There is a lot of additional data injected and I am lost on how I can pass some data with additional meta data.

I am not sure what is going on.. If I try to use:

```
Content = new StringContent("test content")
```

on the client side I get "test content" but I get this:

> Content:
> {"version":"1.1","content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Type","value":["text/plain; charset=utf-8"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"Retrieved
> Forecasts","headers":[],"trailingHeaders":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}

Here is my Blazor code:

Client:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        //forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");


        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await Http.GetAsync("WeatherForecast");

        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Response Weather");
            //forecasts = (await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>()).ToList<WeatherForecast>();
            Console.WriteLine("Content: " + await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            //forecasts = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherForecast[]>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).ToList<WeatherForecast>(); // Doesn't work
            forecasts = await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>(); //Doesn't work

        }
    }
    catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
    {
        exception.Redirect();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        WeatherForecast[] weather =  Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();


        HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = OK,
            ReasonPhrase = "Retrieved Weather",
            //Content = new StringContent("test content")
            //Content = JsonContent.Create<WeatherForecast[]>(weather)
            //Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weather))
        };

        string test = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  // This looks correct!
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you use Newtonsoft? I've found there are a lot of scenarios with STJ where I don't get the right result, and switching over fixes it.

Comment: @PeterMorris thanks but switching to Newtonsoft did not help.

Comment: I will try with a very basic app to make sure BlazorBoilerplate isn't doing something funny with it.